# bash: cannot open file with command

Tags: bash, file-io, command-line

When I run

```
$ lsusb -D /dev/bus/usb/001/002
```

from the command line, it works.  However, when I run

```
$(lsusb -D /dev/bus/usb/001/002)
```

I get the error

> Cannot open  /dev/bus/usb/001/002

In the BASH script, I am running the command in a while loop which also gets its input from lsusb:

```
while read line; do 
        if [[ some_condition ]]; then
                bus_Num=$(echo "$line" | cut -d' ' -f2)
                dev_Num=$(echo "$line" | cut -d' ' -f4)
                $(lsusb -D /dev/bus/usb/$bus_Num/$dev_Num)
        fi
done < <(lsusb)
```

However, when I run the command outside the loop, it works, leading me to believe that the `< <(lsusb)` command is locking the file.  Is there a way to access the file (maybe make sure that lsusb is opening the file in read-only), without saving the info into a variable and running `lsusb -D` after the loop ends?

Comment: What are you trying to do? `$(cmd)` is attempt to execute output of command. It is unlikely you need that here.

Comment: You probably want to capture the output of the `lsusb` command and store it in a variable, like this `var=$(lsusb...)`

Comment: @keltar What I'm trying to do is read the usb devices, and if one is of interest, get more info about it by calling lsusb on that specific device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well doing `$(lsusb -D /dev/bus/usb/001/002)` is wrong since the output of it is expanded to run as another command however `Cannot open /dev/bus/usb/001/002` is not really an error from the output being called but an error message sent by `lsusb` itself so besides not using `$()`, you also have to verify that `/dev/bus/usb/001/002` is indeed an existing or active device.

I also noticed something significant with your loop. You may need to use another file descriptor to make sure none of your internal commands would eat up input:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read -u 4 __ BUS_ID __ DEV_ID __ PV_ID __ NAME; do
    DEV_ID=${DEV_ID%%:*}  ## Remove the colon.
    if [[ $NAME == *something* ]]; then
        echo "Trying $NAME"
        lsusb -D "/dev/bus/usb/$BUS_ID/$DEV_ID"
    fi
done 4< <(exec lsusb)
```

- `exec` is just optional.

Comment: The $() was a problem, but so was the fact that I did not remove the colon from the device ID...*sigh*.  Very sloppy.  Thank you for catching that konsolebox.  In your first line, what is that name of that substitution so that I can research it further?  I'm guessing that for each name I put there, the field is substituted into that name.  For instance __ is kind of like sending it to /dev/null and then the second field is put into BUS_ID, etc?

Comment: @MrUser Yes you're correct about that. Each line read is split with separators based from `$IFS`. BUS_ID, DEV_ID, PV_ID and NAME are the only fields needed. `__` gets the last value before NAME but that's not significant to us.

Comment: From `help read`: Reads a single line from the standard input, or from file descriptor FD if the -u option is supplied. The line is split into fields as with word splitting, and the first word is assigned to the first NAME, the second word to the second NAME, and so on, with any leftover words assigned to the last NAME. Only the characters found in $IFS are recognized as word delimiters.

Answer (score 1):

When you run `some_command`, it executes the command and sends the command's standard output to the terminal (unless redirected).

When you run `$(some_command)` it executes the command and captures the command's stdout, returning it to you. Normally you would store that output in a variable (`var=$(some_command)`). Since you did not store the output, **the output of the command is given back to the shell *as a command to exectute***.

Example:

```
$ echo "echo foo"
echo foo
$ $(echo "echo foo")
foo
```

Comment: Thank you for clarifying.  This is basically my first week with BASH and it's hard sometimes to google things like "$() vs () vs (()) vs [[]]"  I know, I know...RTFM.